# Is there a way to update history location of app registered in single spa when url changes?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, react-router-dom, history, single-spa

I have two apps within single-spa, one in React and other in Vue.
The React app uses history library for navigation. Below given are my React app files:

history.js

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

export const history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename: '/myapp,
    forceRefresh: true 
})
```

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import history from ‘../history.js’; 

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }

   render(){
       return (
           <Router history={history}>  
             <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/user" component={User} />
               <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
             </Switch>
           <Router />
      )
  }
}
```

I face an issue when:

1. I’m at the path https://localhost:3000/myapp/user of React app and I switch to the Vue app (using navbar menu).
2. Now when I switch back to React app, the url shows https://localhost:3000/myapp which ideally should load my Home component.
3. But now the history still has the old location (https://localhost:3000/myapp/user) which then loads the old User component.

Is there a way to update history when the url changes?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find how to change history, but I want you to fix some grammar errors. Meybe fixing errors can help you.

history.js

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({
    basename: '/myapp, // basename: '/myapp',
    forceRefresh: true 
})
```

App.js

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/user" component={User} /> // <Route path="/user" component={User} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it was a typo. And in App.js, I want those components to load only for the given exact paths.

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to getting to routing mechanisms to work together. This is an interesting problem and I have two ideas that could work:

### Idea 1: refresh the page

If you're okay with a full reload, refreshing the browser whenever you switch between Vue and React would probably reset the state in both routers so that they both read the initial state they loaded on and continue.

I would do this by assigning `window.location.href = '/myapp'` inside any event handler that would cause the transition to React. It should reload the browser and navigate to that page. This *should* work if your react app is loading at that path.

### Idea 2: Use `createMemoryHistory` and sync it with Vue's router

Instead of feeding `react-router` a "browser router", you can instead pass it a "memory router". As the name implies, the memory router holds state in memory (instead of using the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API)).

I'm thinking you can wire up the events from Vue's router to react-router's memory router and get them in sync like that. I think you can call [`history.push`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v4/docs/GettingStarted.md#basic-usage) inside of Vue's [global after hooks](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-after-hooks).

Something like this:

```js
//  I have not tested this, take this as inspiration
const router = new VueRouter({/* ... */});
const history = createMemoryHistory({/* ... */});

router.afterEach(({fullPath}) => {
  history.replace(fullPath, {fromVueRouter: true});
});

history.listen(location => {
  if (location.state?.fromVueRouter) return;

  router.replace(location.pathname);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Right now I've solved it in a similar way you have mentioned as Idea 1.
 if (window.location.pathname === '/myapp') {
   history.replace('/')
 }
else {
history.replace(window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))  // to get right url on back press.
}

But I was looking for a cleaner way of doing it without unnecessary refresh.
About Idea 2, I should not be changing anything in the Vue app configuration.